# Multiple inner joins in JPQL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have been trying to write a `jpql` query, but getting the exception,

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [SELECT * FROM com.highpeak.tlp.datastore.model.TaskRequestModel trm inner join trm.task t inner join trm.task.matterId m inner join trm.task.matterId.client c  where trm.isActive is true and trm.task.isActive is true and trm.task.matterId.isActive is true and trm.task.matterId.client.isActive is true  trm.requestedFor =:owner order by trm.createdAt DESC]

My query is

```
SELECT * FROM TaskRequestModel trm inner join trm.task t 
inner join trm.task.matterId m inner join trm.task.matterId.client c 
where trm.isActive is true and trm.task.isActive is true and 
trm.task.matterId.isActive is true and 
trm.task.matterId.client.isActive is true trm.requestedFor =:owner 
 order by trm.createdAt DESC"
```

What might be the issue?

**Update**
I even tried

```
SELECT * FROM TaskRequestModel trm inner join trm.task t inner join 
t.matterId m inner join m.client c where trm.isActive is true and 
t.isActive is true and m.isActive is true and c.isActive is true and 
trm.requestedFor =:owner  order by trm.createdAt DESC
```

Comment: Too many problems.  Don't mix `GROUP BY` with `SELECT *`.  Ever.

Comment: Same error occurs even after removing group by....

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that `is true` is valid JPQL (it's certainly not valid SQL).  So you should be just asserting columns directly in your `WHERE` clause if they be boolean.  Besides this, you were also missing an `AND` in the `WHERE` clause.  Putting this all together, and removing the incorrect `GROUP BY` clause gives this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TaskRequestModel trm
JOIN trm.task t 
JOIN trm.task.matterId m
JOIN trm.task.matterId.client c 
WHERE
    trm.isActive AND
    trm.task.isActive AND 
    trm.task.matterId.isActive AND
    trm.task.matterId.client.isActive AND
    trm.requestedFor =:owner 
ORDER BY trm.createdAt DESC
```